# Encrypting and Decrypting a token with a C# ASHX handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, encoding, handler

I've read a nice guide a few days ago about generating a token on the server's side to have the time of the token's creation within the token, along with "Guid.NewGuid()" 's encryption.

However, I've tried to adjust the results to have a user's username within the token, rather than the date time. I'm close, but I cannot extract the username itself, I can only receive it with some random letters after it.

**Code of the ASP.NET generic handler to GENERATE the token upon identification**

```
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
if(postType == "identify")
{
        byte[] binName = encoder.GetBytes(name);
        byte[] key = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        string _token = Convert.ToBase64String(binName.Concat(key).ToArray());
        // The above creates a token with the name and the "key", works well
}
```

**Code of the generic handler to decrypt the token (see example for result)**

```
if(postType == "check")
{
       string _token = dict["token"] as string;
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(_token);
        string theCode = encoder.GetString(data); // This will get both the username and the GUID key within
        context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(new Code { eCode = theCode })); // Returns in JSON, irrelevant to the question, it works well
}
```

EXAMPLE: If the name would be "user", then the varialbe "theCode" would hold the value of "userXyZxYzXyZ" (while XyZ stands for the GUID's "random" key).

*I think it is fair to say that my question is how to separate this GUID's key from the username upon decryption*

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid` != encryption

Comment: [Relevant link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6267555/969613)

Comment: Dont you just need to add some character in between them so you can then split them when you do your decryption like when you encrypt then add a | in between the name and the guid.

Comment: @spender Yeah, thanks. I used the wrong term. My meaning was different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guid is 38 characters long, so the name will be `theCode.SubString(0, theCode.Length - 38)`.  Alternately, you can compare the current user's name with theCode: `theCode.StartsWith(name)`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the length.