# Are unique IDs (GUID's) good for website image filenames?

Tags: php, image, seo, guid

I'm having a debate with a fellow programmer (PHP) and we both disagree when it comes to GUIDs. Assuming that information about each image is being stored in a DB and has its own primary key (int).

What reasons could there be for using a unique ID for the image filename, beyond not having to worry about duplicate filenames?

I don't want to disregard his methodology, but it doesn't sit well with me either.

Thanks!
Ben

**Update:**
Having heard many +1's for GUIDs, how might SEO be affected by "randomly" generated image filenames? (Thanks Sukumar)

Comment: Regarding SEO see http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/007366.html In this case, I don't think primary key vs GUID makes any difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What reasons could there be for using a unique ID for the image filename, beyond not having to worry about duplicate filenames?

Using an auto-increment primary key for a file name would make it possible to guess other images' URL's, which may be something you do not want - depending on how your system works, users could, for example, gain access to images that aren't intended for publication (yet).

I think using unique IDs is quite a good idea.

Comment: 10 seconds here make sense..., +1

Comment: Wow that was an extremely quick and concise response, thank you! Security wins over slight db bloat, everytime.

Answer (score 5):

### Advantages of using GUID for filenames

- Get unpredictable filenames.
- Names that scale (don't need to worry about renaming files when DB is sharded).

### Disadvantages of using GUID for filenames

- Have to store additional data in the database.

### Advantages of using DB primary key for filenames

- Saves storage by reducing the need for an additional column.

### Disadvantages of using DB primary key for filenames

- Creates predictable filenames allowing users to "guess".

**Summary**: It is a trade-off you need to consider based on your requirements. More preference seems to be given to choosing GUIDs though.

Comment: Thanks Sukumar, very clear list. GUIDs have a lot more punch than I gave them credit for. Would an SEO consideration be better as a separate question?

Comment: SEO consideration could perhaps be an additional point in the answer. You could clarify your question further and improve this answer as well, making it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

`UUID` is great when you need to have *unpredictable* filenames, so no one could download all the files without having the right urls.

Comment: This is not entirely correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517497/how-secure-are-guids-in-terms-of-predictability

Comment: @OverZealous: oh, my fault. Did not know that. So it is unpredictable for about 99% of people )) Btw, any proofs that GUID is actually predictable?

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote my comment.  I didn't mean to come across so harsh!

Comment: @OverZealous: it wasn't at all. I admit I don't know a lot of things and becoming smarter is my aim of being here ;-)

Comment: @OverZealous: According to wikipedia "Cryptanalysis of the WinAPI GUID generator shows that, since the sequence of V4 GUIDs is pseudo-random, given full knowledge of the internal state, it is possible to predict previous and subsequent values". So perhaps it is not good enough for just small amount of companies/projects

Comment: Thanks zerkms, 99% unpredictability is more than sufficient for our purposes :)

Comment: @Ben: you need to know that I've taken number 99 from nowhere, it is just a way to say "really a lot". I think the real value is much closer to 100 though. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in a database using a primary key I would suggest using that as unique ID (and thus filename). It doesn't make much sense to have two unique columns in a database identifying one resource. I wouldn't use an auto-increment field for this primary key by the way. It's to easy to guess other image ids which may be unwanted.

The choice between the two is a matter of taste I think. We use both. The filenames are what is mostly used but then you'd have to have rights to view the file. We use a unique ID as well but thats to avoid rights checking and enabling someone to share images to non-users.