# okta OAuthError: Could not acquire access token from authorization code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, okta, okta-api

I am using OKTA.

Looks like that i got an error when clicking on login button:

> OAuthError: Could not acquire access token from authorization code.

My app is in LIVE. All the settings in app dashboard  look correct, because I took a simple js sdk in index.html file and made it work. So Something happens on okta Size. I am using social/identity providers.

Anyone has ever used okta and reached this error?

Another hint is that their support somehow on their back-end admin panel checked and they also get another error message: "`Cannot call API on behalf of this user`"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the issue was because the security secret key didn't match with the one in the IDP database.

If you have generated manually the secrete key check that the key is created using ssh256 hash.
You can find how to generate a secrete key here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44013730/4878365