# Is there any drawback in using a combination of RandomNumberGenerator class and base 64 encoding for generating passwords?

Tags: c#, .net, random

In my web service I need to generate passwords that are strong and can be represented as a string. Currently I use [`System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) and generate a large enough (let's just assume it is really large enough) array of random bytes and then encode it using base 64 and return that to the user.

This way I have a random password which is generated using a suitable-for-cryptography PRNG (not class `Random`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3307275/57428) for details on why class `Random` is not okay here) and which can be represented as a string and sent in an email, shown in an interface or typed in or copy-pasted by the user.

Is anything inherently wrong with this scheme from the security standpoint?

Comment: If you ensure that the password is transmitted securely between the web service and the user and back, then your scheme is secure.

Comment: @dtb: Of course, I can't ensure that at all times and I won't make any assumption about that. I'm asking only about the password construction process.

Comment: Base64 doesn't add or remove any security, if that's your question. But just using a suitable-for-cryptography PRNG doesn't make your scheme secure; you also need to think about how to transmit it to the user, how important it is that someone who shouldn't have a password doesn't get one, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the *Random* and the *RandomNumberGenerator* classes are basically *pseudo-random number generators* and as they are based on algorithms, there is a limit as to how random their outputs can be.

But when compared to the *Random*, the *RandomNumberGenerator* class is considered as a *Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator* as it makes use of a quite a few other environmental parameters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom) for ensuring randomness. Some of the parameters are:

- The current process ID
- The current thread ID
- The tick count since boot time
- The current time
- Various high-precision performance counters
- An MD4 hash of the user's environment block
- High-precision internal CPU counters

Do go through the following link which is an interesting read regarding randomness: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/computers-are-lousy-random-number-generators.html

---

For the purpose normal usage scenarios such as generating passwords as in your case, the use of the *RandomNumberGenerator* class is more than enough (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

*"To generate a cryptographically secure random number suitable for creating a random password, for example, use a class derived from System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator such as System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider."*

Answer (score 3):

With regard to whether there is anything inherently wrong with this scheme from a security standpoint, I would consider sending a password via e-mail to be a security risk in itself. Even if the e-mail is encrypted when going down the wire, it's still going to be stored on a medium that you have no control over.

Plus, the types of passwords that you're generating will not get memorised by users, making them more likely to get written down on a sticky note, or something similar, for all to see.

Comment: So this is a commment on his question posted as an answer?